# How does the z transform work in practice?

Tags: transformation, control-theory, z-transform

**What I've found**

I've implemented a PID controller using the equations 7 and 9 of [this article](http://www.controlsystemslab.com/doc/b4/pid.pdf), which states that:
$$\frac{U(s)}{E(s)}=K_p+\frac{K_i}{s}+K_ds$$
Translates to $$\frac{U(z)}{E(z)}=K_p+\frac{K_i}{1-z^{-1}}+K_d(1-z^{-1})$$
Meaning that I had to implement:
$$u(k)=u(k-1)+(K_p+K_i+K_d)e(k)-(K_p+2K_d)e(k-1)+K_de(k-2)$$
It looks like it's working fine, so I wanted to understand how they got this equation but I don't end up with the same results.

**What I've done**

Apparently the z-transform is linear so I just have to find the z-transform of the integrator $\frac{1}{s}$ and the derivative $s$. Tables give the z transform of the integrator as $\frac{1}{1-z^{-1}}$ but do not give that of the derivative (why?) so I tried to do both this way:
$$\text{integral}(k)=\text{integral}(k-1)+\frac{\text{input}(k)+\text{input}(k-1)}{2}T$$
$$\text{derivative}(k)=\frac{\text{input}(k)-\text{input}(k-1)}{T}$$ 
Which, if previous values are multiplied by $z^{-1}$, yields:
$$\text{integral}(z)=\text{integral}(z)z^{-1}+\frac{\text{input}(z)+\text{input}(z)z^{-1}}{2}T$$
$$\text{derivative}(k)=\frac{\text{input}(k)-\text{input}(k)z^{-1}}{T}$$ 
Rearranged:
$$\frac{\text{integral}}{\text{input}}(z)=\frac{T}{2}\frac{1+z^{-1}}{1-z^{-1}}$$
$$\frac{\text{derivative}}{\text{input}}(z)=\frac{1-z^{-1}}{T}$$ 
**Question**

Why don't they give the same answer? How does the z-transform work in practice (including how to get from the z transfer function to discrete time)? I could not find anything well explained online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula for $U(z)/E(z)$ cannot be right - it makes no reference to sample time. There are many good references with correct formulas for discrete PID controllers. They are not unique - there are several slightly different constructions that implement the idea of PID control.

It is not completely clear what a $z$-transform of a function of $s$ would be. One of the reasons why an exact differentiator cannot be built in discrete time has to do with causality.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, so the paper was wrong at that point. Considering I only want an approximation properly implemented in a microprocessor which the link to Kp Ki and Kd is exactly known (so that simulations are representative), is my method right? If not, what should I do to end up with an iteration equation u(k)=K1u(k)+K2u(k-1)+K3u(k-2) (can you quote the good references you have mentioned?)?

Comment: Any textbook on digital controls will give formulas and explain how you can approximate $s$ by a function of $z$ to implement controllers basically which do what you want if the sampling rate is good enough. The last 2 formulas you wrote are on the right track. 

Åström and Wittenmark is a good textbook but there are many other fine ones. http://www.amazon.com/Computer-Controlled-Systems-Theory-Electrical-Engineering-ebook/dp/B00CWR4V0Y/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1404153935&sr=1-1&keywords=astrom